# model.predict() always returns a single array with length step count

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, kaggle, tpu

I am trying to create a model for this [Kaggle competition](https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/tpu-getting-started). A lot of the code that I am using here is from the getting started notebook in that competition. For extra context, I am using Tensorflow 2.15.0 and I am using the Kaggle notebook to write and run this code.

To summarize, the dataset I am using involves a series of images of 104 different species of flowers loaded in from TFRecord files split into training, validation, and test sets.

When pre-processing the training data, I duplicate the dataset a few times and apply data augmentation to all the images in that dataset.

For my model, I am using the Xception model pre-trained on imagenet modified to have a classifier with 104 categories at the end of it.

The model trains fine although with some weird errors:
`model_pruner failed: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Graph does not contain terminal node StatefulPartitionedCall.`
`model_pruner failed: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Graph does not contain terminal node AssignVariableOp.`

```
import math, re, os
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib as plt

print("Tensorflow version " + tf.__version__)

# Detect TPU, return appropriate distribution strategy
try:
    tpu = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver()
    print('Running on TPU ', tpu.master())
except ValueError:
    tpu = None

if tpu:
    tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(tpu)
    tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(tpu)
    strategy = tf.distribute.TPUStrategy(tpu)
else:
    strategy = tf.distribute.get_strategy()

print("REPLICAS: ", strategy.num_replicas_in_sync)

IMAGE_SIZE = [512, 512]
GCS_PATH = "/kaggle/input/tpu-getting-started" + '/tfrecords-jpeg-512x512'
AUTO = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE

TRAINING_FILENAMES = tf.io.gfile.glob(GCS_PATH + '/train/*.tfrec')
VALIDATION_FILENAMES = tf.io.gfile.glob(GCS_PATH + '/val/*.tfrec')
TEST_FILENAMES = tf.io.gfile.glob(GCS_PATH + '/test/*.tfrec')

CLASSES = ['pink primrose',    'hard-leaved pocket orchid', 'canterbury bells', 'sweet pea',     'wild geranium',     'tiger lily',           'moon orchid',              'bird of paradise', 'monkshood',        'globe thistle',         # 00 - 09
           'snapdragon',       "colt's foot",               'king protea',      'spear thistle', 'yellow iris',       'globe-flower',         'purple coneflower',        'peruvian lily',    'balloon flower',   'giant white arum lily', # 10 - 19
           'fire lily',        'pincushion flower',         'fritillary',       'red ginger',    'grape hyacinth',    'corn poppy',           'prince of wales feathers', 'stemless gentian', 'artichoke',        'sweet william',         # 20 - 29
           'carnation',        'garden phlox',              'love in the mist', 'cosmos',        'alpine sea holly',  'ruby-lipped cattleya', 'cape flower',              'great masterwort', 'siam tulip',       'lenten rose',           # 30 - 39
           'barberton daisy',  'daffodil',                  'sword lily',       'poinsettia',    'bolero deep blue',  'wallflower',           'marigold',                 'buttercup',        'daisy',            'common dandelion',      # 40 - 49
           'petunia',          'wild pansy',                'primula',          'sunflower',     'lilac hibiscus',    'bishop of llandaff',   'gaura',                    'geranium',         'orange dahlia',    'pink-yellow dahlia',    # 50 - 59
           'cautleya spicata', 'japanese anemone',          'black-eyed susan', 'silverbush',    'californian poppy', 'osteospermum',         'spring crocus',            'iris',             'windflower',       'tree poppy',            # 60 - 69
           'gazania',          'azalea',                    'water lily',       'rose',          'thorn apple',       'morning glory',        'passion flower',           'lotus',            'toad lily',        'anthurium',             # 70 - 79
           'frangipani',       'clematis',                  'hibiscus',         'columbine',     'desert-rose',       'tree mallow',          'magnolia',                 'cyclamen ',        'watercress',       'canna lily',            # 80 - 89
           'hippeastrum ',     'bee balm',                  'pink quill',       'foxglove',      'bougainvillea',     'camellia',             'mallow',                   'mexican petunia',  'bromelia',         'blanket flower',        # 90 - 99
           'trumpet creeper',  'blackberry lily',           'common tulip',     'wild rose']                                                                                                                                               # 100 - 102


def decode_image(image_data):
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_data, channels=3)
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32) / 255.0  # convert image to floats in [0, 1] range
    image = tf.reshape(image, [*IMAGE_SIZE, 3]) # explicit size needed for TPU
    return image

def read_labeled_tfrecord(example):
    LABELED_TFREC_FORMAT = {
        "image": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string), # tf.string means bytestring
        "class": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),  # shape [] means single element
    }
    example = tf.io.parse_single_example(example, LABELED_TFREC_FORMAT)
    image = decode_image(example['image'])
    label = tf.cast(example['class'], tf.int32)
    return image, label # returns a dataset of (image, label) pairs

def read_unlabeled_tfrecord(example):
    UNLABELED_TFREC_FORMAT = {
        "image": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string), # tf.string means bytestring
        "id": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),  # shape [] means single element
        # class is missing, this competitions's challenge is to predict flower classes for the test dataset
    }
    example = tf.io.parse_single_example(example, UNLABELED_TFREC_FORMAT)
    image = decode_image(example['image'])
    idnum = example['id']
    return image, idnum # returns a dataset of image(s)

def load_dataset(filenames, labeled=True, ordered=False):
    # Read from TFRecords. For optimal performance, reading from multiple files at once and
    # disregarding data order. Order does not matter since we will be shuffling the data anyway.

    ignore_order = tf.data.Options()
    if not ordered:
        ignore_order.experimental_deterministic = False # disable order, increase speed

    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames, num_parallel_reads=AUTO) # automatically interleaves reads from multiple files
    dataset = dataset.with_options(ignore_order) # uses data as soon as it streams in, rather than in its original order
    dataset = dataset.map(read_labeled_tfrecord if labeled else read_unlabeled_tfrecord, num_parallel_calls=AUTO)
    # returns a dataset of (image, label) pairs if labeled=True or (image, id) pairs if labeled=False
    return dataset

# data augmentation model
data_augmentation = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Resizing(IMAGE_SIZE[0], IMAGE_SIZE[1]),
    tf.keras.layers.RandomFlip("horizontal_and_vertical"),                    # Randomly flip the image horizontally and/or vertically
    tf.keras.layers.RandomRotation(0.2),                                      # Randomly rotate the image by 20%
    tf.keras.layers.RandomTranslation(height_factor=0.2, width_factor=0.2),   # Randomly translate the image by up to 20%
    tf.keras.layers.RandomZoom(0.2),                                          # Randomly zoom the image in or out by up to 20%
    tf.keras.layers.RandomContrast(0.2),                                      # Randomly change the contrast of the image by up to 20%
])

# image resizing
resize_image = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Resizing(IMAGE_SIZE[0], IMAGE_SIZE[1])
])

def get_training_dataset(num_augmentations):
    loaded_dataset = load_dataset(TRAINING_FILENAMES, labeled=True)
    dataset = loaded_dataset

    # add additional images to the dataset
    for i in range(num_augmentations):
        dataset = dataset.concatenate(loaded_dataset)

    # perform data augmentation on the dataset
    dataset = dataset.map(lambda image, label: (data_augmentation(image), label), num_parallel_calls=AUTO)
    dataset = dataset.repeat() # the training dataset must repeat for several epochs
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(2048)
    dataset = dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(AUTO) # prefetch next batch while training (autotune prefetch buffer size)
    return dataset

def get_validation_dataset(ordered=False):
    dataset = load_dataset(VALIDATION_FILENAMES, labeled=True, ordered=ordered)
    dataset = dataset.map(lambda image, label: (resize_image(image), label), num_parallel_calls=AUTO)
    dataset = dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
    dataset = dataset.cache()
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(AUTO)
    return dataset

def get_test_dataset(ordered=False):
    dataset = load_dataset(TEST_FILENAMES, labeled=False, ordered=ordered)
    dataset = dataset.map(lambda image, ids: (resize_image(image), ids), num_parallel_calls=AUTO)
    dataset = dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(AUTO)
    return dataset

def count_data_items(filenames):
    # the number of data items is written in the name of the .tfrec
    # files, i.e. flowers00-230.tfrec = 230 data items
    n = [int(re.compile(r"-([0-9]*)\.").search(filename).group(1)) for filename in filenames]
    return np.sum(n)

NUM_TRAINING_IMAGES = count_data_items(TRAINING_FILENAMES)
NUM_VALIDATION_IMAGES = count_data_items(VALIDATION_FILENAMES)
NUM_TEST_IMAGES = count_data_items(TEST_FILENAMES)
print('Dataset: {} training images, {} validation images, {} unlabeled test images'.format(NUM_TRAINING_IMAGES, NUM_VALIDATION_IMAGES, NUM_TEST_IMAGES))

# Define the batch size. This will be 16 with TPU off and 128 (=16*8) with TPU on
BATCH_SIZE = 16 * strategy.num_replicas_in_sync
AUGMENTATIONS = 4

ds_train = get_training_dataset(AUGMENTATIONS)
ds_valid = get_validation_dataset()
ds_test = get_test_dataset()

print("Training:", ds_train)
print ("Validation:", ds_valid)
print("Test:", ds_test)

np.set_printoptions(threshold=15, linewidth=80)

print("Training data shapes:")
for image, label in ds_train.take(3):
    print(image.numpy().shape, label.numpy().shape)
print("Training data label examples:", label.numpy())

print("Test data shapes:")
for image, idnum in ds_test.take(3):
    print(image.numpy().shape, idnum.numpy().shape)
print("Test data IDs:", idnum.numpy().astype('U')) # U=unicode string

EPOCHS = 12

with strategy.scope():
    # Xception model pre-trained on the imagenet dataset
    pretrained_model = tf.keras.applications.Xception(
        weights='imagenet',
        include_top=False,
        input_shape=[*IMAGE_SIZE, 3]
    )
    pretrained_model.trainable = True

    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        pretrained_model,
        # ... attach a new head to act as a classifier
        tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=len(CLASSES), activation='softmax'),
    ])

    # compile model
    model.compile(
        optimizer='adam',
        loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
        metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy'],
    )
model.summary()

# Learning Rate Schedule for Fine Tuning #
def exponential_lr(epoch,
                   start_lr = 0.00001, min_lr = 0.00001, max_lr = 0.00005,
                   rampup_epochs = 5, sustain_epochs = 0,
                   exp_decay = 0.8):

    def lr(epoch, start_lr, min_lr, max_lr, rampup_epochs, sustain_epochs, exp_decay):
        # linear increase from start to rampup_epochs
        if epoch < rampup_epochs:
            lr = ((max_lr - start_lr) /
                  rampup_epochs * epoch + start_lr)
        # constant max_lr during sustain_epochs
        elif epoch < rampup_epochs + sustain_epochs:
            lr = max_lr
        # exponential decay towards min_lr
        else:
            lr = ((max_lr - min_lr) *
                  exp_decay**(epoch - rampup_epochs - sustain_epochs) +
                  min_lr)
        return lr
    return lr(epoch,
              start_lr,
              min_lr,
              max_lr,
              rampup_epochs,
              sustain_epochs,
              exp_decay)

lr_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler(exponential_lr, verbose=True)

# Define training epochs
STEPS_PER_EPOCH = NUM_TRAINING_IMAGES * AUGMENTATIONS // BATCH_SIZE

with strategy.scope():
    history = model.fit(
        ds_train,
        validation_data=ds_valid,
        epochs=EPOCHS,
        steps_per_epoch=STEPS_PER_EPOCH,
        callbacks=[lr_callback],
    )

cmdataset = get_validation_dataset(ordered=True)

images_ds = cmdataset.map(lambda image, label: image)
labels_ds = cmdataset.map(lambda image, label: label).unbatch()

cm_correct_labels = next(iter(labels_ds.batch(NUM_VALIDATION_IMAGES))).numpy()
cm_probabilities = model.predict(cmdataset, steps=NUM_VALIDATION_IMAGES//BATCH_SIZE)

print(cm_probabilities)
print(len(cm_probabilities))
print(tf.shape(cm_probabilities))

cm_predictions = np.argmax(cm_probabilities, axis=-1)
print(cm_predictions)
```

I then ran model.predict() on the validation dataset. What I wanted to do is to see how well the model performs when classifying each of the classes and create a confusion matrix using this data since model.evaluate() only determines how well the model performs overall. I will also be planning to use model.predict() to run the model on the test set and submit the predictions.

When running the model.predict() function, if I recall correctly, I should get a list of arrays for each image in the validation set which contain the weights for each class. However, I run into an issue where model.predict() is instead returning a single array with a length equal to the step size which there were 29 in this case (3712 validation images / 128 batch size).

```
[127.99999  127.999985 128.       ... 127.999985 127.999985 127.99999 ]
29
tf.Tensor([29], shape=(1,), dtype=int32)
2
```

I've tried different models (I did ResNet50V2, VGG16, and a basic CNN model) and they all yielded the same problem where I only get a single array of size 29. My only guess as to what is going on here is ether an issue with my classification layer or with the dataset, perhaps shape related.

Comment: I tested it with a Dataset from dummy np data and on cpu, and for me it runs. Can you replace your image input with random numpy data of the same shape? If it works with that, you have to take a look at `TFRecordDataset` I presume. TF version for me is 2.13.

Comment: I reran the code on CPU with the same dataset using MobileNet for 1 epoch and the predictions worked fine. My only guess to what is going on here is that there is something wrong with my TPUStrategy.